# I started out on PL/SQL Development on SQL Developer. How will my work in the DEV environment be pushed to QA and then eventually PROD?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have an understanding that it might be the DBA's job to push the changes, much like a refresh, but without the DML (Data Manipulation).

Any comments/suggestions will be great!

Comment: Usually I've seen the developer submit their work as a script for DevOps / DBA to run. Sometimes the dev will just submit the names of the objects they created, and the DBA will pull the DDL themselves from DEV to QA, etc.

Comment: hopefully you have a source control system to track changes of your db code, outside of any database. and also hopefully you have test/dev systems. and finally hopefully you or someone is writing migration/upgrade/install scripts to have your changes applied - generally with something like SQLcl/SQLPlus

Comment: This is a great question, but it's too broad for Stack Overflow.  This is a large topic, and there are many different ways to approach the problem.  Adequately describing even a single approach would require an entire chapter.  And people will violently disagree with each other about this topic.  I have strong opinions on this topic, but the best advice is probably "do whatever other people in your organization do."

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple answer for this, but essentially the task of deploying code is similar for any computer language, with the main differences for the database component being

1. We can't drop and rebuild tables because we need to keep their contents.
2. Our code compiles in the database, so there are no binaries to deploy.

The first rule for PL/SQL development is that you should always, always work from source-controlled files, for example the code for `mypackage` would be in a source file named `mypackage.pck` (or whatever file extension works best with your chosen IDE, as long as it's not `.sql`). Don't edit database source code directly except for trivial testing when you don't care about keeping the changes.

Some sites only ever do incremental deployments, while others use a full teardown and rebuild from a release branch for major releases, which takes a bit more thought but is ultimately cleaner. Then deployment consists of running the scripts, recompiling the schema and perhaps running some tests and checks to ensure it has worked. You'll need a branching strategy, perhaps some kind of *'run everything in this folder'* script, and ideally some tools such as Team City or Jenkins to automate as much as possible, though I don't think there is as much out there ready-made for PL/SQL as there is for more mainstream languages such as Java.

The deployment process is usually performed by an application support team as it does not require any DBA privileges unless you are creating schemas or roles etc, although some sites may organise support roles differently.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Partially it will involve DBA. But, as the developer, you probably need to provide the entire DDL script by exporting (probably in a file) to the DBA to deploy.

Check 'Importing and exporting SQL scripts' part of this link for exporting db scripts: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25309/sql_rep.htm#BABBHEHA